# Is a TFS branch a physical or logical snapshot?

Tags: tfs, branch

When code is branched in TFS using the branch method, is the code physically or logically branched?  By logical, I mean is it just a changeset (changed deltas) or are all of the files copied?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Branched files are not copied within the TFS database. A new version of the file will not be created until the branched version is modified. This is why creating a branch on a large project does not take forever.

**Source:**

http://www.codeplex.com/BranchingGuidance/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Isolation%20for%20Collaboration&referringTitle=Home

The fourth paragraph under branching explains that it does not create a separate copy of identical files:

> Creating branches uses very little
>   additional storage space. The server
>   minimizes the storage required by only
>   keeping one copy of identical content
>   no matter how many different files are
>   contained in the folder. So, if you
>   have 100 copies of a 1 MB file and all
>   of the files are identical, the server
>   will store only 1 MB, not 100 MB. When
>   you create a new branch and commit,
>   all of the files in the new branch
>   that are identical to the files in the
>   source branch point to the same
>   content. The result is that a branch
>   consumes very little additional
>   storage space, and that storage space
>   expands only when the branched file
>   becomes different than the source. And
>   even when files change, Team
>   Foundation Server employs a
>   differencing engine to analyze changes
>   between files and once again optimize
>   storage space.

Microsoft Branching Guidance PDF:

http://geeks.netindonesia.net/downloads/etc/TFS-Branching.pdf

Comment: Downvote with no comment? This quote is directly from the Microsoft Branching guidance document and I have found it to be 100% accurate. We create branches on a very large project and the branches are created nearly instantly and take very little storage space.

Comment: Personal experience: with TFS making a branche would cost significant time while it is instantaneous now we have migrated to Subversion. I'm not sure about the inner workings, but TFS does more than a small administrative transaction.

Comment: @Teun - I think it is fair to say branching in and of itself is not performed routinely (I've typically seen it done only when breaking off dot releases).  My concern is with space more than time.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Branches are stored logically and are not a direct copy of the parent.

Long answer: Bill Heys, a VS ALM Ranger, wrote a detailed blog post describing how branches and file history are stored in TFS.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/05/05/how-tfs-stores-files-and-calculated-deltas-on-versioned-files.aspx