# Does creating a branch in TFS 2010 copy the code base?

Tags: branch

As far as I know, bracnhing in TFS 2008 simply duplicates the code base.

Is this also true for TFS 2010?

Thanks...

Comment: Can you please cite some source that says that "bracnhing in TFS 2008 simply duplicates the code base"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is true for TFS 2010. See the [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

TFS 2010 does not create a copy of the code when a branch is created. This question has been answered here:

[Is a TFS branch a physical or logical snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537301/is-a-tfs-branch-a-physical-or-logical-snapshot/11106807)

In addition, MS employee and VS ALM Ranger wrote this blog post to describe in good detail how branching is handled internally by TFS:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/05/05/how-tfs-stores-files-and-calculated-deltas-on-versioned-files.aspx

> When you create a new branch (for example from MAIN -> DEV), a shallow copy of each of the files on the source branch (MAIN) is made. Following this, both branches refer to the same copy of each file (the file content), and only metadata is copied to the new branch (DEV). Thus, when a new branch is created, only metadata is copied. Only when the first real change is made in this new branch, is a new deltafication chain is started for changed file(s).

Comment: This answer contradicts the accepted answer - who is correct here? I gave +1 because the listed link has very good information. Also, based on what I have read so far, this answer seems to be correct.

Comment: @radim, take a look at the msdn blog post I referenced.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is true for 2010 as well.

Comment: Can you add a reference to something that confirms that please?